# Highlight text - how to have consistent padding?

Tags: css, text, highlighting

I can't get this paragraph to display as I want to. The padding between the text and the end of the background should be consistent on every line as shown in this image

[image: Picture of Padding Problem]

**HTML**

```
<div id="title-image-container">
    <?php echo '<img src="'.get_post_meta($id, 'title-image', true).'">' ?> 
    <div class="highlight-title"><p><?php the_title(); ?></p></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#title-image-container {
    float: left;
}
.highlight-title {
    position: relative;
    top: -300px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
}
.highlight-title p {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline; 
    color: #000;    
    font: 1.9em 'oswald';
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
#content img {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Try to remove padding and set margins on text.

Comment: Thanks but it only introduces a left margin on the first line instead of the left padding.

Comment: @psot: Remove the solution from the question, and create an answer with that solution. Then accept your own answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will make your work done--

```
p{padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
text-align:justify;
word-spacing:5px;}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and update. It would be a better solution due to IE8 not supporting box-shadow.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by simply replacing the padding with box-shadow, based on comments found on another [website](http://samcroft.co.uk/2011/jquery-plugin-for-inline-text-backgrounds/).

```
.highlight-title p {
    box-shadow: 10px 0 0 0 red, -10px 0 0 0 red;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline; 
    color: #000;    
    font: 1.9em 'oswald';
    line-height: 60px;
}
```